# Extending functionality to support HTTP clients

Tags: spring-integration

Need some pointers on extending an existing functionality (implemented in SI project) to support SOAP based Web service.

Here is my scenario:

I have a SI project that implements a core functionality.  Currently the SI project supports message exchange via JMS. 
The core functionality is well tested and running fine in Production region as a standalone app.

Now an enhancement request has come wherein I need to provide support for SOAP clients. The SOAP client will utilize the same core functionality as the JMS client.

1. **jms-endpoint.xml** : Defines JMS request-reply interaction details.
2. **core-func.xml**    : Defines the core functionality (simplified for this post).  Based on the employee Id passed in the JMS message,  it return Promotion Eligibility flag.

Question:
1. Is it possible to add support for SOAP clients by utilizing the existing SI code?

I don't want to move the core functionality to a servlet container and retest the entire standalone SI project that is running fine for JMS clients.

## jms-endpoint.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" .... >
  <import resource="queue.xml"/>
  <import resource="core-func.xml"/>

  <int:channel id="inboundMessage"/>
  <int-jms:inbound-gateway request-channel="inboundMessage"
                       request-destination="requestQueue"  default-reply-destination="responseQueue"/>
</beans>
```

## core-func.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" ....>
  <int:chain input-channel="inboundMessage">
    <int:service-activator ref="employeeService"    method="getEmployeeData"/>
    <int:service-activator ref="eligibilityService" method="getPromotionEligibility" />
  </int:chain>

  <bean id="eligibilityService"  class="com.samples.service.EligibilityService" />
  <bean id="employeeService"   class="com.samples.service.EmployeeService">
     <property name="employeeDao" ref="employeeDao"/>
  </bean>
  <bean id="employeeDao"  class="com.samples.dao.EmployeeDao" />   
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question has a lot of unrelated information. At least IMO.
Anyway let me try to answer to this one:

> Could you please advise on the approach I should follow to extend the existing functionality to HTTP clients.

Yes, you always can do that and not only to HTTP, but any other desired and required protocol.

For SOAP one you should take a look into [Spring Integration WS](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ws.html) module what is fully based on the [Spring WS](http://projects.spring.io/spring-ws/) project.

For this purpose your application must become web-based. Of course you can take a look into [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) on the matter.

Not sure what you would like to hear else...

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have edited the question for better understanding. Hopefully my question will be clear now.

Comment: Great! I see now (or not...). Well, how are you going to introduce SOAP to your application without servlet container? As I said: you always can have as much entry points in your application as possible. With the same core functionality. Only the problem that servlet container is a requirement. Real or embedded but still. Yes, you can use JMS transport for SOAP as well, but will your client be happy do not interact with you via standard HTTP transport?

Comment: Standard HTTP transport is being widely used and clients would want it. From your comments my takeaway is that for a new SI project I would use a servlet container as it gives me the flexibility to add HTTP endpoints later on without too much pain/cost.  Migrating an existing standalone SI app to a servlet container (to introduce SOAP) may not be well accepted by clients due to duplication of testing effort.

Comment: For implementing the scenario I posted above I am thinking of a workaround/solution.  Create a new SI project in a servlet container to provide SOAP support.  It will host the WSDL and act as the proxy service provider.  This new SI app will use jms outbound gateway to forward the incoming request to the queue. The existing standalone SI app is already configured to listen to the queue and it can process and reply.  The core SI app need not be changed.

Comment: That will work too. If you really are going to do a new app, you really don't have choice unless reuse that entry point which already exists in other app. My idea was just about one more functionality to existing app with reuse those core channels from WS adapters. But solution is good from the micro service perspective

Answer (score 0):

Run your application using [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) - it provides an embedded servlet container; tomcat by default but you can choose others.

There are several [Spring Integration Samples, including this one](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/barrier) that use boot.